# Count of similar data based on different range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

table name - flights in sql server 2008

```
   date       name
2003/04/29  air_France
2003/04/05  Dale_avia 
2003/04/08  Dale_avia 
2003/04/08  Dale_avia 
2003/04/02  Dale_avia 
2003/04/05  Aeroflot  
2003/04/25  Aeroflot  
2003/04/01  Don_avia  
2003/04/01  Don_avia  
2003/04/01  Don_avia  
2003/04/13  Don_avia  
2003/04/13  Don_avia  
2003/04/13  Don_avia  
2003/04/14  Don_avia  
2003/04/14  Don_avia  
2003/04/01  Don_avia  
2005/11/04  British_AW
2005/11/07  British_AW
2005/11/07  British_AW
2005/11/09  British_AW
```

Now I tried to filter occurrence of name in particular range of dates based on date column, I mean 3 sets for 4th month 2003 on dates between 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30…..But I struggle to frame correct query

**I trying to get Like below**

```
name       | 1-10  | 11-20  | 21-30
---------------------------------- 
Don_avia   |   4   |   5    |  0 
Aeroflot   |   1   |   0    |  1
```

i cant able to proceed in correct way with correct query....

please help me ..thanks in advance !!!!!!

Comment: It is almost impossible to read the embedded image.  You should put the data directly into the question as text.

Comment: What was your SQL that you tried?

Comment: @almas - `select name,COUNT(name) from flights where date between '2003/04/01' and '2003/04/10' group by name`

Comment: i can able to get output for particular range...but i want to get for multiple range of dates like i mentioned in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  name,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(date) BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1-10",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(date) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "11-20",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(date) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "21-30"
FROM flights
GROUP BY name
```

Test it on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f129/2)

Comment: i get error like these `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @CIPHER tested, it works on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f129/2) (MS SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT
  name,
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM flights AS F1 WHERE F.name = F1.name AND DAY(Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 10) AS "1-10",
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM flights AS F2 WHERE F.name = F2.name AND DAY(Date) BETWEEN 11 AND 20) AS "11-20",
  (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM flights AS F3 WHERE F.name = F3.name AND DAY(Date) BETWEEN 21 AND 30) AS "21-30"
FROM flights AS F